# Aggregate interval data to hourly

Tags: sql-server, count

I am getting data for 15 minutes interval. I would like to aggregate this data to hourly.Can anybody advise how should i do this query to sum the interval values and display it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do a simple GROUP BY with DATEPART applied to the time column. I'm assuming that you'll always get a row every 15 minutes and you don't need to worry about gaps in the data.

```
SELECT 
  code
, date_column AS [date]
, DATEPART(HOUR, time_column) AS hourly
, SUM(value) AS value
FROM test_table
GROUP BY
  code
, date_column
, DATEPART(HOUR, time_column);
```

The following references may be useful to you:

- [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql)
- [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql)
- [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql)

Answer (score 3):

In light of sum of every N hours as @wmasmaddy mentioned in the comment, here is the generic solution based on Joe's answer

```
declare @N int = 2;--change to your requirement
SELECT 
 code
, date_column AS [date]
, DATEPART(HOUR, time_column)/N*N +(N-1) AS N_hourly -- +(N-1) is to make the last hour as the identity hour, you can change to your own preference.
, SUM(value) AS value
FROM test_table
GROUP BY
  code
, date_column
, DATEPART(HOUR, time_column);
```